# How to fix random trimming of text in DirectWrite?

Tags: c++, windows, directwrite

I'm displaying the fps of my application. When I change the size or position of the text, it sometimes isn't rendered properly and the layout rect is big enough.

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Example code, only snippets:

Variables:

```
IDWriteTextFormat* textFormat;
WCHAR* text = L"Example0101";
int textSize = (int)wcslen(text);
D2D1_RECT_F rect = {};
ID2D1SolidColorBrush* brush;
```

Constructor:

```
Game::Game(ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* D2DRenderTarget) {
this->D2DRenderTarget = D2DRenderTarget;

CoInitialize(NULL);
CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IWICImagingFactory,
    (LPVOID*)&WICImagingFactory);

DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED, __uuidof(IDWriteFactory), (IUnknown**)&writeFactory);

writeFactory->CreateTextFormat(
    L"Arial",
    NULL,
    DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_REGULAR,
    DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL,
    DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL,
    16.0f,
    L"en-us",
    &textFormat
);

rect.left = 480.0f;
rect.top = 275.0f;
rect.right = 1000.0f;
rect.bottom = 1000.0f;

D2DRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), &brush);
}
```

Drawing:

```
void Game::draw() {
D2DRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.9f, 1.0f));

D2DRenderTarget->DrawTextW(text, textSize, textFormat, rect, brush, D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_NO_SNAP, DWRITE_MEASURING_MODE_GDI_CLASSIC);
}
```

RenderTarget:

```
D2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
    D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
    D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(
        window,
        D2D1::SizeU(960, 540),
        D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS_IMMEDIATELY),
    &D2DRenderTarget
);
```

[image: an image of it again]

Everything is very normal. I guess this is solved with some kind of smoothing or maybe I just forgot something.

Comment: Can you provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I added some code

Comment: Could you check if it's any better with DWRITE_MEASURING_MODE_NATURAL?

Comment: All 3 measuring modes have the same result

Comment: I just noticed that I'm using a wrong ratio for my window while using 16:9 for the d2d area, so this thread can be closed :P